# Re-import packages in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I'm aware of options to re-import data to tables using table_exists_action and can give options like skip,append or replace for the data.

But is there an option to re-import packages (re-create) into the database if they are already existing without throwing up an error like

```
" Package PKG_1 already exists"
```

I basically have packages which have some changes in them and re-import to another environment where there packages are already existing.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://community.oracle.com/thread/959980 and https://community.oracle.com/thread/838380 the only way to do this is to use the `SQLFILE` parameter to `impdp` to create a script. Then replace `CREATE PACKAGE` with `CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE` and then execute the script.

Comment: There's this doc from Oracle that says there's no option indeed: [444236.1 DataPump Replacement Of Existing Procedures And Functions, Sequences](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=444236.1) - a bit old, but I don't see anything in newer versions that would help in this regard.